# SQL Count number of occurences of combinations and split into separate columns by count

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with vendors and companies:

| Vendor | Company |
| --- | --- |
| V1 | C1 |
| V2 | C1 |
| V3 | C1 |
| V4 | C1 |
| V1 | C2 |
| V2 | C2 |
| V4 | C2 |
| V1 | C3 |
| V2 | C3 |
| V5 | C3 |
| V6 | C3 |

I am trying to show how many unique and shared vendors each company has:

| Company | UniqueVendors | SharedVendors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1 | 3 |
| C2 | 1 | 2 |
| C3 | 2 | 2 |

I am able to identify Unique / Shared vendors by counting there occurences, e.g.

```sql
    SELECT [Vendor], COUNT([Vendor]) AS VendorCount 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Vendor
    HAVING COUNT([Vendor]) = 1
```

but I do not know how to proceed and count the shared vendors and then get the result in separate columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation along with exists logic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Company,
           CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT 1
               FROM yourTable t2
               WHERE t2.Company <> t1.Company AND
                     t2.Vendor = t1.Vendor
           )
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS unique_cnt
    FROM yourTable t1
)

SELECT Company,
       SUM(unique_cnt) AS UniqueVendors,
       COUNT(*) - SUM(unique_cnt) AS SharedVendors
FROM cte
GROUP BY Company;
```